# How does Stack Exchange use OpenBSD?

Tags: discussion, donation

The [Stack Exchange Gives Back 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-exchange-gives-back-2014/?cb=1) post mentioned the engineering team donated some money to “tools and organizations that make what we do possible”, which included OpenBSD.

The last publication I recall about the StackExchange datacenter was [this blog post by Nick Craver](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/), which mentions several Microsoft technologies, but doesn’t mention OpenBSD at all.

I’m certainly not against donating money to OpenBSD, but I was wondering where does Stack Exchange use OpenBSD?

Comment: The OpenBSD project is more than an OS. OpenSSH is an OpenBSD project for example, as are numerous other secure software projects.